# Bounded function and second derivative implies bounded derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is a twice differentiable real-valued function on the real line such that $|f(x)| \le 1$ and $|f''(x)|\le 1$ for all $x$. Find, with proof, a constant $b$ such that $|f'(x)| < b$ for all $x$.

My instinct is to use the Mean Value Theorem, which gives me
$$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=|f'(\xi)|, \quad \text{for some } \xi \text{ between } x \text{ and } y,$$
and
$$\frac{|f'(s)-f'(t)|}{|s-t|}=|f''(\nu)| \le 1, \quad \text{for some } \nu \text{ between } s \text{ and } t.$$

From here, I have been unable to find a expression for the upper bound of $|f'(x)|$ in terms of $|f(x)|$ and $|f''(x)|$.

Any suggestions on where to go from here, or perhaps a different way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're almost done: for any interval $[x,y]$ with $y-x=1$, you have some $\xi \in [x,y]$ such that $| f'(\xi)| = |f(y)-f(x)| \le 2$. Now, if you pick any other point $\alpha \in [x,y]$, from the second equation you get the estimate $|f'(\alpha)-f'(\xi)| < 1$, hence $|f'(\alpha)| < 3$ for all $\alpha \in [x,y]$. But $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary points with distance $1$, so that $|f'|$ is bounded by $3$ on the whole real axis.

Exercise: try to reduce the bound to $2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If you can show that $f'(x)$ is uniformly bounded on **every** interval $[a,b]$, then it is also bounded on $\Bbb R$.

Also, try to transform the problem to the case where $f(a)=f(b)=0$, it is much easier that way (integrate by parts or Taylor's theorem).