# Upper bound for the derivative of a twice differentiable function.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

If $f$ is twice differentiable function and $|f|<\alpha, |f''|<\beta$ in the domain $x>a$, then which of the fallowing may be upper bound for $|f'|$...

a) $\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$

b) $2.\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$

c) $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$

d) $4.\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$.

By taking $f(x)=\sin x$ c) is discarded. For other options, if a) is true then b),d) is also true. if b) is true then so d). So, the answer could be d).

I were trying to prove by Mean Value Theorem, but didn't get answer. Help is needed, Thankx in advance.

Comment: A similar problem can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905598/bounded-function-and-second-derivative-implies-bounded-derivative.